# Как получить суммы значений для записей, сгруппированных по значениям внешней таблицы?

Tags: sql

У меня есть таблица `records`, в которой содержатся данные мониторинга. Например, есть поле `time`, которое выводит значение в милисекундах. Запись выглядит приблизительно так:

```
(id, task_id, name, time)
```

Есть вторая таблица, назовём её `tasks`. В ней есть следующие поля:

```
(id, global_task_id)
```

Мне необходимо создать таблицу, в которой будет следующее:

```
(global_task_id, time_sum)
```

где `time_sum` будет являться суммой всех полей `time`, которые будут содержаться в записях, для которых `global_task_id` будет одинаков. То есть, для каждого `global_task_id` собрать сумму всех `time` из таблицы `records`. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Надеюсь, `tasks.id` - уникальное поле (первичный ключ), и `records.task_id = tasks.id`? если нет - то без подзапроса не обойтись... да и задача станет неоднозначной.

Comment: да, Вы правы в обоих случаях

Comment: Ну тогда [@teran](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/223826/teran) дал ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

так что ли? обычный джойн, группировка и суммирование.

```
SELECT global_task_id, sum(time)
FROM tasks AS t
INNER JOIN records AS r ON (r.task_id = t.id)
GROUP BY global_task_id
```